# Open link in iOS app from mail

Tags: ios, email

I am sending email from my iOS app. The message is composed from server and sent. The message contains a `link`. Now I want that when I click on this `link` in the mail from iPhone/iPad- it should open in the same app(through which I am sending the mail) installed on my device.

Is this possible? If yes, how do I do this?

Comment: You might want to set Custom URL for your app and then call it accordingly to open the app..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428697/shared-link-that-will-open-my-app-or-the-app-store/24429079?noredirect=1#comment37797191_24429079 
u can check my answer..

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible

for this you have to set url schema in info-plist.

set link like urlShemaName://?[link to be open] in the mail

implement the method in app delegate as bellow

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
NSLog(@"%@",[url scheme]);
NSLog(@"%@",[url query]);
return YES;
```

}

```
[url query]
```

this returns the parameter which are passed after ? from custom url. from that method you can open this link in in-app browser.

if you want I can give you demo code.

Comment: Sure, it would be great if you could give a demo

Answer (score 0):

please download demo code from this link [DEMO CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy53omqw6vts5mc/custonUrlShema.zip) run this code in simulator or device then open safari and type `moinuddin://?http://www.google.com` end press enter you will redirect to application and google page will be open

same thing will be done via mail

Comment: I downloaded your app and did what you suggested. But what I want to do is, Click on a button which is in the mail- a link will be called(for eg.- http://someApp/register.php). So instead of redirecting it to this link in browser, I wish to open the app(or a particular page in the app). How do I do this by URL Scheme you have mentioned in plist?

Comment: in the link your button like `moinuddin://?url=http://www.google.com&page=moin` in delegate you get the `[url query]` as string seprate string with & and check parameter like if "page" == 1 then go to page 1 and else go to other page

Comment: The button gets generated from server side, I can't link it to anything else. It just redirects to say for eg. `http://www.google.com&page=moin`. I can't append `moinuddin://?url=` at server side.

Comment: without schema identifier it is not possible. server have to sent `moinuddin://` which is tells to OS that open application with schema id "moinuddin" so without schema id it is not possible.

Comment: OK got it. I ll have to change the URL on server to detect that the call is made from iOS. Thanks.